# How to make sure that OpCache is caching files of my website ? (Prestashop)

Tags: php, prestashop, opcache

I am trying to use Opcache on my Prestashop Website, I installed it and it seems active (see [here](https://supercartable.com/phtest.php)) , but I want to be sure that it's actually caching the PhP scripts.

I have been looking into the configuration array that delivers some info about Opcache (see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-get-configuration.php)) but I want to see exactly which files are cached (and possibly also where).

Also, is there a way to see the effect of Opcache on my website between: when activate vs deactivate ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Back when opcache came out we used to use something [like this](https://github.com/rlerdorf/opcache-status) to have a visualization of the cache. I don’t think 5.6 had a file system portion, that was added in 7.0 as a secondary cache (if my memory serves).